# GraphQL Spring Boot Web Interceptor to return an error response if headers not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, spring-webflux

I'm trying to create logic that will intercept all `/graphql` requests, check if headers are present and add them to MDC, and if not "reject" the request with an appropriate error.

First attempt was to add it to a registered `AsyncHandlerInterceptor#preHandle`, where I threw an `IllegalArgumentException`. Unfortunately, the `DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter` does not pick it up.
Then I tried a a [WebInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-M4/reference/html/#web-interception), but again the resolver doesn't see this exception.

Here is the interceptor, I'm very new to reactive, so pls don't judge lol.
It seems to work correctly, when the header is present, but not when the exception is thrown.

```
@Bean
public WebInterceptor headerInterceptor() {
    return (webInput, chain) ->
        chain.next(webInput)
            .doFirst(() -> {
                String header = webInput.getHeaders().getFirst("some-header");
                if (header != null && !header.isEmpty()) {
                    MDC.put("some-header", header);
                } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
            })
            .doFinally(s -> MDC.clear());
}
```

Interceptor code (not reached):

```
public class SomeDataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter extends DataFetcherExceptionResolverAdapter {

    @Override
    protected GraphQLError resolveToSingleError(Throwable throwable, DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        if (throwable instanceof ConstraintViolationException || throwable instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
            return GraphqlErrorBuilder
                    .newError(environment)
                    .errorType(BAD_REQUEST)
                    .message(throwable.getMessage())
                    .build();
        } else {
            return super.resolveToSingleError(throwable, environment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, Did you figure this out ? Been bugging me for for sometime , this issue. I have a similar use case. I want to intercept incoming request and add values in MDC.

Comment: @PriyakDey hey, have a look at the answer I posted. Not perfect in terms of centralised error handling, but it was ok in my case

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, we are using kickstarter and WebInterceptor  is from spring-graphql. So I solved this using an Aspect to my resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
public class GraphqlHeaderInterceptor implements WebInterceptor {
...
    @Override
    public Mono<WebOutput> intercept(WebInput input, WebInterceptorChain chain) {
        return chain.next(input)
                .doFirst(() -> {
                     // fill MDC or throw Exception if no header
                })
                .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(errResult(input, ex)))
                .doFinally(s -> MDC.clear());
    }

    private WebOutput errResult(WebInput input, Throwable ex) {
        var error = GraphqlErrorBuilder
            .newError()
            .errorType(BAD_REQUEST)
            .message(ex.getMessage())
            .build();

        var result = ExecutionResultImpl.newExecutionResult().addError(error).build();
        return new WebOutput(input, result);
    }
...
}
```

Which is good enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

Add @ControllerAdvice

This worked for me

Comment: This is not an answer. Please remove and use comments.